# Have Slide menu cover view controller, not move it aside (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS app I am using SWRevealViewController to add menu functionality. It works great, however my client wants to make the menu cover the current view controller, not move it to the right.

I mean something like this:

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

The author of this library told me to implement the following, where I can get current offset of the menu and move the current view controller by that offset by doing something like that:

```
let rvrw = self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth
var bounds = navigationController!.view.bounds
bounds.origin.x = rvrw
navigationController!.view.bounds = bounds
```

The problem is that the menu is behind it. I would like to know how I can do that in this library or if there is another library with similar implementation and that functionality as well.

I have found tons of libraries, but all of them are pushing the controller not covering it. I have found one or two which do it way I need, but they missed some features (like being under navigation bar), were outdated or buggy.

Answer (score 0):

[SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/) offers some customization options

> documented in the SWRevealViewController.h header file.

It seems as though the *frontView* is the part with "WatchKit" in your example and the *rearView* is the menu.

In that case, you might be able to use `setFrontViewPosition` with the value [`FrontViewPositionLeftSide`](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/blob/master/SWRevealViewController/SWRevealViewController.h#L158-160), which gives the *frontView*

> // Left position, front view is presented left-offseted by rightViewRevealWidth

If that does not work, you could also try `FrontViewPositionLeftSideMost`, which gives the position

> // Left most position, front view is presented left-offseted by rightViewRevealWidth+rigthViewRevealOverdraw

<sub>I did not have the setup at hand to try this.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as you think :)  http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/ I'm using example from this tutorial. Try it. Anyway thanks for edit. My english is far from perfect and I was in hurry.

Comment: @Makalele: you are welcome for the edit. The tutorial contains few examples and I thought it might work that way. Thanks for trying it out.